# PageSize in itext 7

Tags: itext7

The static values in iText 7 for PageSize are only for ISO 'A' sizes, whereas 5 had about 52 values including the somewhat quaint Quarto and Penguin sizes.

Is this going to be a permanent state of affairs, or will it be included at some point? I know I can make a Rectangle the size I want, but this helps form losing the piece of paper all time...

Comment: This was an oversight. As far as I know, adding other page sizes is part of the next sprint. Also: while I'm writing the documentation, I discover things that don't work the way I expect it. These things get fixed while I'm writing. Hence it can happen that I document things that will work in iText 7.0.1, but that don't work in iText 7.0.0. This is very much back to the grassroots of open source for me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in `7.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and will be available since `7.0.1`.

Now the available page sizes are: `A0`-`A10`, `B0`-`B10`, `LETTER`, `LEGAL`, `TABLOID`, `LEDGER`, `EXECUTIVE`.